# ASP.NET Core FindByEmailAsync is not responding and getting error 500

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

Using ASP.NET Core with the Identity framework.

I have a project running on Azure, with a SQL Server database, a web site and an API.

Suddenly, today when trying to login to the system (from the app that calls the API), it is stuck for around 15 seconds and then I get an error http 500.

I try to run the API function that authenticate the user from the local env. and was able to reproduce the bug.

The first line of the function is :

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Username);
```

This is the line the program is stuck till getting error message 500.

I don't even know how to approach this, I try to add a line that retrieves one of the user details, just to make sure the API can still talk to the database and it works fine.

How can check what is wrong with it? If I had the implementation of this function, maybe I can debug it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the thrown exception when you reproduced the error in your local environment?

Comment: I wanted to attach a screenshot for you, so i did it again and now i was able to get the user with this line of code...it hasnt been working in the last 3 hours (maybe more) and now suddenly it is working, how is this possible....

Comment: Stuck for 15 seconds sounds about as long as the default retry policy.  Without further information, I would guess it's a transient / network error.

Comment: From your question, There seems to be nothing wrong with your code, It may be a network error,I think  you can check the  azure application insights if there is something woring in that 3 hours